# Printing a table from an arraylist using multiple object types

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to convert a string to a date, and then populate several array lists with user input. I am also trying to print the array lists in a tablet format. Unfortunately I keep getting an error with the formatter and with printing using a for loop to pass each array list value. I am required to use MVC. Controller class:

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    
    public class Controller {
     View view = new View();
     Model model = new Model();
    
    
    public void Run(){
    
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date today = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    String firstDate = view.invoiceDate();
    String secondDate = dateFormat.format(today);
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(firstDate,formatter);
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(secondDate,formatter); 
    
    model.setDaysLeft(date1, date2);
    long daysBetween = model.getDaysLeft();
    model.buildL1(view.Department());
    model.buildL2(view.Amount());
    
    
if(daysBetween > 0)
{
 
    view.showInvDate(firstDate);
    view.showTodayDate(secondDate);
    view.showDaysLeft(daysBetween);
    model.buildL3(date1);
    model.buildL4(daysBetween);
    runAgain();
}
else
{
    view.showInvDate(firstDate);
    view.showTodayDate(secondDate);
    view.showDaysLeft(daysBetween*-1);
    model.buildL3(date1);
    model.buildL4(daysBetween);
    runAgain();
}
}   

  
public void runAgain(){
            if (!view.exit()) {
                Run();
            }
            else {
                for (int i =0; i < model.depList.size(); i++){
                view.printInvoiceHeader();
                view.printInvoice(model.getdepList(i), model.getAmtList(i), model.getDueDList(i), model.getDaysList(i));
                }
            }
        }
}

Model class:


import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Model {
  
    String depName;
    double amount;
    LocalDate dueDate;
    long daysBetween;
    ArrayList<String> depList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> amtList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<LocalDate> dueDList = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
    ArrayList<Long> daysLList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public String getDepName() {
        return depName;
    }
    public void setDepName(String depName) {
        this.depName = depName;
    }
    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public LocalDate getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }
    public void setDueDate(LocalDate dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }
    public void setDaysLeft(LocalDate date1,LocalDate date2){
        long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1,date2);
    }
    public long getDaysLeft(){
        return daysBetween;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> buildL1(String depName){
        depList.add(depName);
        return depList;
    }
    public String getdepList(int i){
        return depList.get(i);
    }
    public ArrayList<Double> buildL2(Double amount){
        amtList.add(amount);
        return amtList;
    }
    public Double getAmtList(int i){
        return amtList.get(i);
    }
    public ArrayList<LocalDate> buildL3(LocalDate dueDate){
        dueDList.add(dueDate);
        return dueDList;
    }
    public LocalDate getDueDList(int i){
        return dueDList.get(i);
    }
    public ArrayList<Long> buildL4(Long daysBetween){
        daysLList.add(daysBetween);
        return daysLList;
    }
    public Long getDaysList(int i){
        return daysLList.get(i);
    }  
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am getting several: at 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
 at java.lang.String.format(

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're printing a variable doesn't match with float. I can't say much because your print methods are not there.